# CSV Import Super Slow after upgrading to PHP 7.1 only on live server

Tags: php, drupal, server

We upgraded our production server to a new server and we went from using PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.1 and we host a Drupal 7 website on it.  For the most part, the site seems to be functioning correctly.  The problem I am seeing after the server move is that CSV imports take a super long time compared to before.  The csv import adds each row into the database.

```
  $fp = fopen($file_path, 'r');
  if ($fp === FALSE) {
    // Failed to open file.
    watchdog('ea_test', 'Failed to open %file_path', array('%file_path' => $file_path));
    $context['finished'] = TRUE;
    return;
  }
  fseek($fp, $context['sandbox']['offset']);

  for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) {
    $line = fgetcsv($fp);

    if ($line == FALSE) {
      $done = TRUE;
    }
    // If first line just skipping ahead.
    elseif ($context['sandbox']['records'] < 1) {
      $context['sandbox']['records']++;
    }
    else {
      try {
        db_insert('ea_csv_test')
          ->fields(array(
            'agent_number' => $line[0],
            'total_signatures' => $line[1],
            'template_number' => $line[2],
            'photo' => $line[3] ? 1 : 0,
            'total_views' => $csv_line[4],
            'total_clicks' => $csv_line[5],
            'annual_cost' => $csv_line[7],
            'monthly_cost' => $csv_line[8],
            'popular_button' => $csv_line[9],
            'month' => $csv_line[10],
            'asof' => date('Y-m-d 00:00:00'),
          ))->execute();
      }
      catch (Exception $e) {
        // By setting the databse error it will fail and display the last bad
        // record. Normally I would log/email this but I think it
        // will send too many. More than likely if one is bad they all
        // will be bad.
        $database_insert_error = $e->getMessage();
        $error = TRUE;
      }

      // Set the current position of the file so it starts from there.
      $context['sandbox']['offset'] = ftell($fp);

      $context['sandbox']['records']++;
    }
  }

  $eof = feof($fp);
```

The thing is on local and on my staging site I cannot replicate the issue.  The only difference is that I am on PHP 7.1.17 on local and PHP 7.1.25 on production.  Both local and prod is using mariadb 5.5.5-10.2.19-MariaDB-log.

**Time Comparison:**

Local / Staging takes 9.51 seconds to process.

Production takes 276.12 seconds to process.

**Edit**

I ran an import directly from the database (without any PHP) and it was super fast. It seems to me it has to be some kind of php setting:

```
truncate TABLE ea_csv_test;
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/test.csv' into table ea_csv_test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

**Edit 2**

Noticed that on Production APCu was not enabled. I enabled it and it helped a little. It went from 276 seconds to 166 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started to compare the innodb settings I found that locally I had `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` set to 2 but in production it was set to 1. Once I changed it to 2 on production it solved my issue.

Based on what I understand is that if set to 2 it logs every second instead of any transaction. Worst case scenario we may lose 1 second of data if the server goes down.  In my case, if we are importing and the server goes down, I would need to reupload anyways because the import would never finish. I'm thinking this would make sense to keep at 1 if we are doing money transactions.